# Enable content assist for *.properties in Eclipse STS

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I have STS 4.4.0.RELEASE installed in my computer which is directly downloaded from [spring.io](https://spring.io)

Content assist works fine for `application.properties` but does not work for `bootstrap.properties`. I have enabled file associations to open `*.properties` with "*Generic Editor - Spring Properties*". But still there is no content assist.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to: *Preferences > General > Content Types > Text* and select **Spring Properties File**.

Now click on **Add** in *File associations*, add the content type accordingly (in my case it was `*.properties`) and click on OK.